# Get selected "PostScript" from PDF

Tags: pdf

I wasn't able to find anything on the internet and I get the feeling that what I want is not such a trivial thing. To make a long story short: I'd like to get my hands on the underlying code that describes the PDF document of a selected area from a .pdf file. I've been looking for libraries or open source readers but couldn't find anything useful yet.

Does there exist something that might be able to accomplish my needs here or anything that might be reused (like an open source reader) to get there a little faster and not having to write everything from scratch?

Comment: The company I work for used to sell a product that did something like this (Amyuni PDF Analyzer) but I think it has been discontinued... maybe you can try to look if there is an evaluation version still available on the website.

Comment: Do you want to get at this programmatically to accomplish a certain goal, or are you interested in examining PDF files to see what they are made off? There are certainly tools to inspect PDF files in this way, they just don't offer "restrict to a certain page area" necessarily.

Comment: A PDF is not really "PostScript underneath" (although they share some concepts). How about a high level library that is able to return a list of objects with their position and size, and then use rectangular clipping to get what objects you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a whole PDF document to PostScript using `pdftops`, one of the utilities from the poppler PDF rendering library.
This utility enables you to convert individual pages, which is at least a start.

If you just want to extract bitmapped images, try `pdfimages` from the same package. This extraction can also be restricted to individual pages.

The poppler library was originally written for UNIX-like systems, but there are a [couple](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-win32/files/?source=navbar) of [windows builds](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) available.

Comment: That it not really what I am looking for since that way I'd have to parse the script myself and somehow find out what someone has e.g. selected with his mouse. I assume that some PDF readers might already be able to capture those elements of a pdf inside such a selection area somehow. I don't know if there is such a library that could help me here of maybe an open source PDF reader that does some work in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

The open source tool from iText called iText RUPS does what you want, showing you all the PDF commands for a particular PDF and allow you to visualize the structure and relationships.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups/